# Partitioning pandas data frame by time range with overlap

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, partitioning, overlap

I have a pandas data frame with a datetime column (and a number of other columns). I want to partition it into frames of some time duration, say 10 seconds, with some predefined overlap, say 2 seconds. So effectively I want to partition the data frame into every 8 seconds (= 10 seconds duration - 2 seconds overlap) but collecting data for next 10 seconds in that partition. So I want partitions corresponding to time (0, 10), (8, 18), (16, 26)... and so on. How can I do it effectively?

As I understand the frequency in Grouper can do partitioning based on time but cannot handle the overlap as I require it.

Comment: Please can you provide a sample and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the source DataFrame has been created as:

```
np.random.seed(0)    # To get repeatable result
i = pd.date_range('2022-01-01 08:00:00', '2022-01-01 08:00:30', freq='S')
df = pd.DataFrame(index=i, data = {'Amount': np.random.randint(0, 100, len(i))})
```

So the time range to select can be based on the index, which operates quite quick.
If your DataFrame has other index, you should set the time column as the index.

Then, to perform some action with overlapping slices according to your definition,
you can run e.g.:

```
for t1 in pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max()
        + pd.Timedelta('1S'), freq='8S'):
    t2 = t1 + pd.Timedelta('9S')
    print(f'Range [{t1},  {t2}]')
    print(df.loc[t1:t2])
    print('----')
```

In the above code there is only a *print* action for the current slice.
The first 2 slices I got are:

```
Range [2022-01-01 08:00:00,  2022-01-01 08:00:09]
                     Amount
2022-01-01 08:00:00      44
2022-01-01 08:00:01      47
2022-01-01 08:00:02      64
2022-01-01 08:00:03      67
2022-01-01 08:00:04      67
2022-01-01 08:00:05       9
2022-01-01 08:00:06      83
2022-01-01 08:00:07      21
2022-01-01 08:00:08      36
2022-01-01 08:00:09      87
----
Range [2022-01-01 08:00:08,  2022-01-01 08:00:17]
                     Amount
2022-01-01 08:00:08      36
2022-01-01 08:00:09      87
2022-01-01 08:00:10      70
2022-01-01 08:00:11      88
2022-01-01 08:00:12      88
2022-01-01 08:00:13      12
2022-01-01 08:00:14      58
2022-01-01 08:00:15      65
2022-01-01 08:00:16      39
2022-01-01 08:00:17      87
----
```

In the target version of code you can:

1. Define a function returning a slice of *df*:

   ```
   def getSlice(t1):
       t2 = t1 + pd.Timedelta('9S')
       return df.loc[t1:t2]
   ```
2. Generate the list of slices in a list comprehension:

   ```
   slices = [ getSlice(t1) for t1 in pd.date_range(df.index.min(),
       df.index.max() + pd.Timedelta('1S'), freq='8S') ]
   ```

When you print *slices[0]* and *slices[1]*, you should get just the same
result as printed above.